# Web page loading slower

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to load a url in webview in android. The url loads fine in the web view. But the problem is the loading time of the webpage in the webview. Sometimes the webpages loads instantly within 1-2 seconds. But sometimes, the web page takes more than 40 seconds to load the webpage in the web view. When I checked the url on the browser, it loads within or less than 2 seconds. The problem is that when the web page takes more than 2 seconds, the white color of the webview is only showing and the users are thinking that the app is stuck or not responding. So they are complaining about the loading time. Is there any way to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to load content coming from internet is to use separate processes than the main one.
An example is:

- you click to open the webview;
- the app doesn't launch the webview activity but a splash screen with the "Loading..." information (plus a logo or an icon);
- this splashscreen activity verifies if the internet connection is
  available; if so, the splash activity launch an AsyncTask which, in a
  separate backgorund thread, download the necessary HTML page (or XML file, etc);
- when the content is correctly downloaded, the splash activity calls
  the Webview activity, giving the necessary data trough an Intent.

This way is commonly used to load internet content on apps; it allows the operator to don't see a freezed activity but a window which suggest that a process is on-going.

Please find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) the official information regarding AsyncTask.

A classic example which uses the SplashScreen/AsyncTask/BackgroundProcess is a RSS Reader; please find [here](http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/) a source code which can help you to understand (check out the SplashScreenActivity).

This is one way to do it, but it's not the only one.

Comment: I posted an example you can donwload! So you have the whole project on your PC! I don't think there is a better way to learn!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on Android 4.4 version. This worked for me

```
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

It is due to some bug in webview for Kitkat version.